# Select MS Access table into SQL Temp Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, import, temp-tables

I need a solution to select a table from access into a temp table in SQL. I looked at bulk insert but from what I understand the source must be a data file so that will not work. Also, I don't want to use the import/export wizard, this has to be done through code as I just need a temp table to perform certain queries on. The query needs to do something like...

```
SELECT * FROM [Access DB] INTO #TempTable (in SQL)
```

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * INTO #TempTable 
FROM [Server_Name].[Database].[Schema].[Table]
```

You will need to add Access data source as a Linked Server to Sql Server. GOTO Obejct Explorer--> SQL Server--> Server Objects --> Linked Servers--> Right CLick and follow the instruction of adding a linked server. Once you have added Access database as a Linked server you can query it by using above command 
Or you can use the OPENROWSET to query Data

```
SELECT * INTO #TempTable    
FROM OPENROWSET(
                'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
                'C:\Program Files\Path_to_Access_Database_File\Database_Name.mdb';
                'admin';'',Table_Name
                )
```

Comment: Yea, but what is the format for selecting the Access DB and table?

Answer (score 0):

Using a linked server your best solution.  Listed below is a technet article on setting them up. You may need to install a driver, I have included the link for the Office 2007 drivers.  Here is a screenshot of my config for an Access 12.0 connection.

http://www.anony.ws/i/2013/11/21/UPm4G.jpg

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782.aspx#SSMSProcedure
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734